# Run angular project on specific host using `ng s` command

Tags: angular, angular-cli

By using the command `ng serve`, We can run an angular project on `http://localhost:4200`

We can also change port using `ng serve --port 4300` and it will be run on
`http://localhost:4300`

Is it possible to run an angular project on a specific host using `ng serve` command? *(some virtual host like `local.xyz.com` (**without port number**))*

Comment: ng serve --host local.xyz.com --port 4300

Comment: @Gopesh Sharma without port number?